# Is this CPU architecture information from lscpu normal?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, cpu-architecture

With command `lscpu` I have output as follows:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              5587.22
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Now in L2 cache is shown 256K? Shouldn't it be 4096K too?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output of `lscpu` is normal. `L2 cache: 256K` is normal output for an Intel dual core processor (2nd generation Sandy Bridge series<sup>**1**</sup> and 3rd generation Ivy Bridge series).

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The smaller L2 cache results in lower latency, and the net result is better performance on the latest dual and quad-core processors.